# Query one value in multiple columns

Tags: php, sql, postgresql, psql

I'm using PHP and PostgreSQL and running the following query:

```
$mobile = 1234;
SELECT pri_mobile, pri_mobile2, sec_mobile, sec_mobile2 
FROM contacts 
WHERE pri_mobile=$mobile 
    OR pri_mobile2=$mobile 
    OR sec_mobile=$mobile 
    OR sec_mobile2=$mobile
```

I want to find out which field the `$mobile` is found in.

One way I can think of is to loop through, and if found in any of the fields, then break the loop. Just wondering if there is any easier way to do this?

Thanks

Comment: What is the output you expect to have ? One column name ?

Comment: @Houari that's correct, just want to output name of the column

Comment: There can only be *1* column matching?

Answer (score 0):

I thought of this solution:

```
select source from
(
select pri_mobile as value, 'pri_mobile' as source FROM contacts
union
select pri_mobile2 as value, 'pri_mobile2' as source FROM contacts
union
select sec_mobile as value, 'sec_mobile' as source FROM contacts
union
select sec_mobile2 as value, 'sec_mobile2' as source FROM contacts
)
where value = $mobile
```

I would not exactly call it pretty though =)

Answer (score 0):

```
$mobile = 1234;

SELECT CASE 
  WHEN pri_mobile = $mobile then 'pri_mobile' 
  WHEN pri_mobile2 = $mobile then 'pri_mobile2' 
  WHEN sec_mobile = $mobile then 'sec_mobile'
  WHEN sec_mobile2 = $mobile then 'sec_mobile2'
END as my_column_name

FROM contacts 

WHERE pri_mobile=$mobile 
    OR pri_mobile2=$mobile 
    OR sec_mobile=$mobile 
    OR sec_mobile2=$mobile
```